# Is there any method or a way to check accesskey permission on the Near account id?

Tags: rust, blockchain, nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

How can I check the account created by an owner is having a full Accesskey or function_call access key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep! You can view the permissions for access keys via our access keys RPC endpoints:

https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc#access-keys

An easy way to do this is to run a `near-cli` command:

`near keys ACCOUNT_ID`

https://docs.near.org/docs/tools/near-cli#near-keys

Comment: is there any similar way with smart contracts?

Comment: There is no way to check the access key permissions inside a smart contract.